# Open Word-office text in Libreoffice - Get rid of marks

Tags: libreoffice

When i open a document in Libreoffice, which has been created in Wordoffice, it appears like this:

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIH30.png)

In black circles are the marks that i would like to get rid of (without removing all of them manually).
Any help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy (Ctrl - C) this "blank" character and Find-Replace all of them (Ctrl - H) with a space character. This should work.